# BarcodeScanner XE7 Android Motorola MC3200 NOt Working with Datawedge

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7, scanning, datawedge

My Motorola MC3200 scanner runs Android 4.1.1.
With Delphi XE7 I made an app, deployed it to the scanner, and it runs.
But ,as soon as the app starts, the scanner does not scan any more.
(absolutly nothing happens when I "pull the trigger". No light. nothing)

There is some program on the scanner called "DataWEdge" that claims that it catches the scan, and sends it to applications as if it where keystrokes.
All it needs is a text-field that has focus. My app has a TEdit with focus.

I assigned my app in this "Datawedge Configuration tool", but no luck so far.

I hope someone can help, because without the scanner this is completly useless (!).

kind regards,

Dirk Janssens.

Comment: Have you checked with Motorola?

Comment: Yes, but it is not yet clear what the problem is. Some think it is a bug in datawedge, some think it is a Delphi issue...

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you can scan without running your app. Datawedge takes care of the scanning (and process the input as KB input)

*I assigned my app in this "Datawedge Configuration tool"*, but no luck so far. - Can you explain what you mean by this? 
You shouldn't have to tell Datawedge anything about your application AFAIK. 
Once datawedge is scanning then we run a WinCE app that captures and processes the scan and all is well.

I suspect that you are doing something in your app that disables or interferes with the datawedge app.

Comment: In the documentation it states, that you can add profiles to datawedge, and the assign applictions to it. Even the Datawedge-demo is assigned that way in a profile. When you open datawedge-app, there are profiles, and each profiles is assigned to one or more applications... The demo works, but only if the profile is enabled, just as one would expect....

Comment: I must say I have never used the profile option, we just setup Datawedge without this and it works when we run our application. I suppose that would be useful if you have more that 1 app requiring different scanning profiles/specifications.

Comment: You are right. You dont *need* a profile, but once you have assigned it to a profile (with application-specific settings) you must enable it, otherwise it won't work.